# how to find multiple patterns in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have two files, file1.csv and file2.txt.

file1 contains:

```
192.1.1.1,1,2,3,9,13,15
192.1.1.2,2,3,9,13
192.1.1.3,3,9,15
```

file2 contains:

```
1,2,3=a
9,13=b
```

The order does not matter i.e 1,2,3=a and also 3,1,2=a. only the presence of these numbers is important.
The first column in my file1.csv consists of IP adresses.

I want my script to look for the numeric patterns listed in file2.txt in file1.csv and if they are present then create a third file with the text present after.

Output file should look like this:

```
192.1.1.1,a,b
192.1.1.2,b
192.1.1.3,none
```

I have tried using awk command to do this. However it works only in case if there are 2 entries like `2,a 1,b` etc.I am confused as to how to proceed when I have to find a combination of numbers.

Comment: Please edit your question and mention that order does not matter as 2 persons have already lost some times on this...

Comment: yes edited. apologies for not including it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not clear you want to check the values in order, which I assume

```
$ awk -F= 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
                   {for(k in a) if($0 FS ~ FS k FS) v=v FS a[k]; 
                    if(v) print $1 v; 
                    else print $1 FS "none"; v=""}' file2 FS=, file1

192.1.1.1,a,b
192.1.1.2,b
192.1.1.3,none
```

the version which doesn't depend on the order specified is little longer

```
$ awk -F= 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
                   {for(k in a) 
                      {n=split(k,t,","); nm=0; 
                       for(i=1;i<=n;i++) if($0 FS !~ FS t[i] FS) nm=1;
                       if(!nm) v=v FS a[k]} 
                       if(v) print $1 v; 
                       else print $1 FS "none"; v=""}' file2 FS=, file1

192.1.1.1,a,b
192.1.1.2,b
192.1.1.3,none
```

Comment: no the order does not matter 1,2,3=a and also 3,1,2=a i just want to check the presence of these numbers.

Comment: Note that here order is important.  Later I'll post another script that ignores it.

Comment: yes sorry i forgot to add that in the question. the order is not important and may be changed.

Comment: Hey I have a question in the above examples how do i get the script to print the numbers that do not match? for eg in the first line it should print 192.1.1.1,15 as 15 does not match anyhwere.Thanks